# PivotViewer - NullReferenceException

Tags: silverlight

I customized the PivotJITViewer program in order to create a dynamic cxml.  But I got runtime error: NullReferenceException.  I tracked and found that the error occurs at PivotServerTools\Collection.cs, AddItem(string name, string url, string description, ItemImage image, params Facet[] facets).  I tried to run debug on this Silverlight project but debugging does not go to the PivortServerTool project. The message shows: 
"A project with an Output type of Class Library can't be started directly.  In order to debug this project, add an executable project to the solution with references the library project.  Set the executable project as the start project."
I set the project.Web that is executable as the start project.  However, I don't understand how to do "with references the library project".
I would greatly appreciate if you can share your experience.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Test Prpject to detect the bug.  It was found that the bug was due to no-match of the attribute names.

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so other will see your question has been answered and be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~